# How to delete the first character of the line only if that line matches with the given pattern

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I need to delete first character  at each line only if the given pattern matches with that line.

I have tried by replacing the first character with space, but space is appending at the each line.

```
 sed -e '/#/s/^/ /' 2.txt > 1.txt
```

I need to remove the # from each line. Kindly suggest me how to make this.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a dot after `^`, so that it would match the first character.

```
sed -e '/#/s/^./ /' 2.txt > 1.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
foo
foo bar #
$ sed -e '/#/s/^./ /' file
foo
 oo bar #
```

If you want to remove the starting `#` symbol then you don't need to use a search pattern,

```
sed 's/^#//g' file1 > file2
```

Comment: first character was deleted in each line. But my file having the like below,                                                   #hi sdklad;adka;
## how are you
## how do u do...So i need to remove the first character only if it have one hash(#). is it possible.

Comment: @sivakumarV update your question ..

Comment: @sivakumarV you mean this `sed 's/^#\([^#]\)/\1/' file`. It would remove the first `#` only from `#hi sdklad;adka;` line

Comment: thank you for your answer.Once more case, sed '/hello/s/^.//' 2.txt. Normally my file having the two # at the beginning of last two line. and my search pattern was 'how' and i need to remove first # only. Is it possible.

Comment: ya its removing first # only, if the line have one #..if the line having consecutive hashes, then also all the # are removing. But i need to remove first hash only, if it having consecutive #.

Comment: You REALLY need to update your question with some representative sample input and expected output as it's very unclear what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/^#//' 2.txt > 1.txt
```

It replaces the `#` at the beginning of a line by an empty string, if there is no `#` at the beginning of the line, then it leaves that line untouched.

Comment: first character was deleted in each line. But my file having the like below,                                                   #hi sdklad;adka;
## how are you
## how do u do...So i need to remove the first character only if it have one hash(#). is it possible.

Comment: Yes, have updated the post

Comment: thanks you. Once more case, sed '/hello/s/^.//' 2.txt. Normally my file having the two # at the beginning of last two line. and my search pattern was 'how' and i need to remove first # only.

Comment: It's hard to get you. If I understand you correct the pattern above should work for that use case.

Comment: @hek2mgl I think he may mean `sed 's/^#\([^#]\)/\1/' 2.txt > 1.txt`